# ClickHouse: Efficient way to aggregate data by different time ranges at

Tags: group-by, clickhouse

I need to aggregate time-series data (with average functions) on different timeslots, like:

- Today
- last X days
- Last weekend
- This week
- Last X weeks
- This month
- List item

  etc...

**Q1:** Can it be done within `GROUP BY` statement or at least with a single query?

**Q2:** Do I need any Materialized View for that?

The table is partitioned by `Month` and sharded by `UserID`

All queries are within `UserID` *(single shard)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

group by with ROLLUP

```
create table xrollup(metric Int64, b date, v Int64 ) engine=MergeTree partition by tuple() order by tuple();
insert into xrollup values (1,'2018-01-01', 1), (1,'2018-01-02', 1), (1,'2018-02-01', 1), (1,'2017-03-01', 1);
insert into xrollup values (2,'2018-01-01', 1), (2,'2018-02-02', 1);

SELECT metric, toYear(b) y, toYYYYMM(b) m, SUM(v) AS val
FROM   xrollup
GROUP BY metric, y, m  with ROLLUP
ORDER BY metric, y, m 

┌─metric─┬────y─┬──────m─┬─val─┐
│      0 │    0 │      0 │   6 │  overall
│      1 │    0 │      0 │   4 │  overall by metric1
│      1 │ 2017 │      0 │   1 │  overall by metric1 for 2017
│      1 │ 2017 │ 201703 │   1 │  overall by metric1 for march 2017
│      1 │ 2018 │      0 │   3 │
│      1 │ 2018 │ 201801 │   2 │
│      1 │ 2018 │ 201802 │   1 │
│      2 │    0 │      0 │   2 │
│      2 │ 2018 │      0 │   2 │
│      2 │ 2018 │ 201801 │   1 │
│      2 │ 2018 │ 201802 │   1 │
└────────┴──────┴────────┴─────┘
```

Comment: How can I receive `null` instead of zero for ROLLUP overalls for non-nullable columns?
_(zero value conflicts with ROLLUP overall zero)_

Comment: right now only using cast to nullable `cast(metric, 'Nullable(Int64)'), cast(toYear(b), 'Nullable(Int32)') y`

Comment: And what about MV with pre-aggregated `-State`? Can it help in this case?

Comment: MV - SummingMergeTree (with day granularity) will help (-state is unnecessary in this case -- it needs only plane sums). Group by will be faster because SummingMergeTree will have fewer rows.

Answer (score 0):

Although there's an accepted answer I had to do something similar but found an alternative route using [aggregate function combinators, specially `-If`](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/combinators#-if) to select specific date ranges.

I needed to group by a content ID but retrieve unique views for the whole time range and also for specific buckets to generate a histogram (ClickHouse's `histogram()` function wasn't suitable because there's no option for sub aggregation).

You could do something along these lines:

```sql
SELECT
  group_field,
  avgIf(metric, date BETWEEN toDate('2022-09-03') AND toDate('2022-09-10')) AS week_avg
  avgIf(metric, date BETWEEN toDate('2022-08-10') AND toDate('2022-09-10')) AS month_avg
FROM data
GROUP BY group_field
```